# How to programmatically get value of built-in resources like colorAccent?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How do you get the actual value of a referenced color. In a layout I can use the following...

```
android:textColor="?android:attr/colorAccent"
```

..and this works in setting the text color of a TextView to the theme defined accent color. How do I get the value of the colorAccent using code at runtime?

Also, how do you discover a list of all the available values, there must be a long list of available colors I could get hold of, but where is that list defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the resource is an Android defined one:

```
  var id = Android.Resource.Attribute.ColorAccent;
```

If the resource is within a Dialog, Widget, etc.. that is not an Android system resource (i.e. to obtain a DatePickerDialog resource)

```
  var id = SomeDatePickerDialog.Resources.GetIdentifier("date_picker_header_date", "id", "android");
```

Using the id obtained:

```
  var typedArray = Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { id });
  var color = typedArray.GetColor(0, int.MaxValue);
  if (color != int.MaxValue)
  {
      Log.Debug("COLOR", color.ToString());
  }
```

The `R` list changes with API/Theme, for the base values available:

- Colors: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html
- Styles: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html
- etc...

But for a complete reference you have to use the Android source for the API the you are looking at:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/

So the colors that are defined in the Oreo beta:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r4/core/res/res/color/

Then look within the specific color xml file for the how it is defined and use that definition to find the actual value of it (in one on the valueXXX files....)

Answer (score 2):

For the example you have you can get that value with something like this:

```
//default color instead the attribute is not set.
var color = Color.Blue;

var attributes = new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.ColorAccent };
var typeArray = ObtainStyledAttributes(attributes);

//get the fist item (we are sending only one) and passing
//the default value we want, just in case.
var colorAccent = typeArray.GetColor(0, color);
```

`colorAccent` will have the `Color` set in your Theme for the `ColorAccent` attribute if any or the default value .

Important to mention that this method `ObtainStyledAttributes` is part of a `Context` so if you are already in an Activity you will find it as part of it but if you are in any other class you will need to pass in the context in case it's not available.

For the full list of available values you can get it from the `Android.Resource.Attribute` class. In VS do an inspection to see the different properties this class has. Maybe Android documentation has a better way though.

Hope this helps.-